# About MicrosoftTeams-TeamFunSettings

Tags: microsoft-teams

Today I found that the *MicrosoftTeams powershell* command *Get-TeamFunSettings* failed  to run when the property GiphyContentRating value is "*Allow all content*".
Error info:

> Get-TeamFunSettings : Error converting value "unknownFutureValue" to
>   type
>   'System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.Model.GiphyRatingType]'.
>   Path 'funSettings.giphyContentRating', line 1, position 844. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Get-TeamFunSettings -GroupId a3f33284-82a5-4643-a43d-401f2568177c
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-TeamFunSettings], JsonSerializationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.GetF
>   unSettings

Answer (score 0):

We are actively investigating this issue and a fix is expected shortly. Note this commend is in beta so instability is not unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just very new but according to the documentation of the command "Allow all content" is not an option. (I do think it should be one, though)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/set-teamfunsettings